# Solutions for $xy’+ay=f(x)$ for $a < 0$ have a limit at $x \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let constant $a < 0$ and arbitary continuous function $f(x)$ such that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}=B$$
>   Prove that any solution for differential equation $xy’+ay=f(x)$ has a limit at $x \rightarrow 0$ and calculate this limit.

I’ve calculated a general solution for this equation assuming $x > 0$: denote $\beta = -a$, then $$y(x)=x^\beta \int_{1}^{x}\frac{f(t)dt}{t^{\beta +1}} + Cx^\beta$$
where $C$ is a constant.

But from this moment I am not able to calculat $\lim_{x \to 0} y(x)$ for any $C$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know we have $x^ay'+ax^{a-1}y=x^{a-1}f(x)$ or $(x^ay)'=x^{a-1}f(x)$ and since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}=B$ then for every solution of this differential equation, $y$ is bounded about $0$, thus $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^ay=\infty$ also $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^a=\infty$ and by l'Hopital
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}y(x)
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^ay(x)}{x^a} \\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(x^ay(x))'}{(x^a)'} \\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^{a-1}f(x)}{ax^{a-1}} \\
&= \dfrac{B}{a}
\end{align}